# Multisite in TYPO3 with individual databases

Tags: typo3

Is it possible to have multisite setup in Typo3 (i.e. only one typo3 instance with multiple sites inside it) with individual database for each of the sites?

Comment: What's the use case behind this question? Why would you have one TYPO3 instance but different databases (and by multisite different domains)? What would be the advantage of a shared vhost over individual vhosts?

Comment: The use case is a University infrastructure with multiple websites for multiple departments. I am still in the investigation phase of the project. Most websites will be accessible to all users (students in this case) but some will only be accessible to users of a certain department (who would require a login). The current setup is that we have multiple individuals websites with individual databases. We want to migrate everything to TYPO3 and are investigating the options. One argument to retain seperate databases is to avoid a single point of failure and less backup, restore and upgrade time.

Comment: For your use case, with TYPO3, you can create a multi-site instance, and define different access right (through groups) for backend as well as for frontend users for each department. In order to migrate the current data from the old website, I suggest you to use the extension external_import.

Answer (score 1):

No you can't, the multisites in the same TYPO3 instance have the same database.

But you can have several DB so that you can manage through TYPO3 tables from another DB, example of LocalConfiguration.php for that :

```
'DB' => [
    'Connections' => [
        'Default' => [
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'dbname' => 'db-default',
            'driver' => 'mysqli',
            'host' => '127.0.0.1',
            'password' => 'xxxx',
            'port' => 3306,
            'user' => 'user-local',
        ],
        'theExternalDb' => [
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'dbname' => 'db-ext',
            'driver' => 'mysqli',
            'host' => 'localhost',
            'password' => 'zzzzz',
            'port' => 3306,
            'user' => 'user-ext',
        ],
    ],
    'TableMapping' => [
        'Table1' => 'theExternalDb',
        'Table2' => 'theExternalDb'
    ],
]
```

**Edit** : a table can only be in one DB, it's the case for table *pages* which contains the pages for all sites.

Comment: Could you point to the official documentation for this?

Comment: You can not have multiple databases because at least, backend user must be in the same DB and many modules and functionalities will be very difficult to implement through multiple DB. 
You can have a look here : https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-inside/8.7/en-us/CoreArchitecture/Database/Introduction/Index.html

Comment: You can have "multiple databases" to e. g. put certain tables into a separate DB that can also be managed by TYPO3. However, you can't have the same table in both databases and expect the CMS to know which table to use. You can either have the whole multi-instance setup in one database, or you create one instance per project. With a clean extension setup for theme and configuration that you can pull via composer, it should be easily manageable.

Comment: @FlorianRival I am confused by your answer. In the first line you mention that typo3 multisites have the same database. Than in the second line you say that i can have several DB (i am reading it as a short form of database).

Comment: @FlorianRival The first image in this [link](https://www.1xinternet.de/en/blog/multisite-vs-multiple-single-websites) describes TYPO 3 multisite with multiple databases. I guess this is what creates confusion for me.

Comment: In the link you mentioned, it's written : "In order to separate the content all websites use separate databases or have separate tables in the same database." for TYPO3, it's the second case but it's not even exactly right, TYPO3 uses the same tables for multi-site but with a root page defined as "root" and this page is associated with the domain in site configuration : https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/main/en-us/ApiOverview/SiteHandling/Basics.html.

Comment: I understand that my answer is a little bit confusing because it's mentioned that you can have several DB but as @pdu wrote, you can have several tables in separate DB but not the same table in separate DB, a table could only be in one DB.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your requirements  as an University with "Multiple Sites" and Access Controll / Restrictions.

TYPO3 is able to Handle Multiple Sites and Restrict Frontend / Backend Users to Specific sites. out of the box.

You Might still Consider Multiple Deployments of the Same code Base to Different servers. so Every Department can Host/manage there own site. while using the Corperate Identy (Sitepackages) and Other Approved Extensions from the Central Authoritiy.

we run a Single codebase for around 20 Individual Deployments. without major problems. but at least for us we had to develop some code for content syncronizsation/distribution (like shared news on all systems). and more automisation. as every step has do be done on 20 deployments.

but over all we are quite happy with the resulting decoupeling.

but i would strongly advice do investigate if the regular TYPO3 multisite feature might be enough to solve your Requirements.

Comment: What do you mean by " Multiple Deployments of the Same code Base". Does this mean the same typo3 instance duplicated with multiple istallation?